# Converting a list of dates into weekdays in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My column F contains a long list of dates. I'm trying to convert them into days of the week (Sunday, Monday etc) and have those in another column.

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to get a value for each F and just treats it like 0 so it fills with Sunday for all of them.

```
Columns("F").SpecialCells(xlConstants).Offset(, 7).Formula2 = WeekdayName(Weekday(Range("F1")))
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Any help appreciated

Comment: You could use: `Columns("F").SpecialCells(xlConstants).Offset(, 7).Formula2R1c1 = "=TEXT(RC6,""dddd"")"`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Formula property, but you just need to return a value.

For example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub weekdays()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range, c As Range
    
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws.Columns("F")
    Set r = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers)
    For Each c In r
        c.Offset(columnoffset:=7) = WeekdayName(Weekday(c))
    Next c
End With
    
End Sub
```

Note:

- `Option Explicit` to require variable declaration.
   *In my opinion, this should be the default but you can set this under `Tools/Options/Editor/Require Variable Declaration` and it will appear at the beginning of any new module*
- Use of the `xlNumbers` value in the `SpecialCells` argument so as to exclude from processing any text values in that column.

[image]

Comment: Does that actually work for you? I can't see how that would work with more than one cell.

Comment: @Rory I don't post anything as an answer that I haven't actually tested. Since the OP did not provide any sample data, I just added a mix of dates and text to column F.

Comment: @Rory Screenshots added. Did you have a problem running it in your environment?

Comment: Yes, I get a Type Mismatch error trying to use Weekday with a multi-cell range (M365 64bit). Your results don't look right anyway as you have Wednesday for all three dates?

Comment: @Rory Thanks for pointing out that error. It worked with my original code, and when I changed it I didn't check that the Weekday being printed actually was correct. I've gone back to my original code.  I wonder, though, why I didn't get the `Type Mismatch` error. Also using M365-64bit.  In any event, the original code seems to work properly.

Comment: Though already referenced the [`WeekdayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/weekdayname-function?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dde-DE%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008932)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) function might not be available yet for all users of MS365 (64bit).

Comment: @T.M. I wasn't aware that there had been any changes to VBA since `VBA7.1` was implemented with Excel 2016. Are you implying that MS made changes to VBA with MS365? Are those changes documented someplace? (I'm not considering the `WorksheetFunction` property of the `Application` object). In any event, my version of VBA is Retail 7.1 Version 1131

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sorry, nothing to do with recent versioning  - I only stumbled on the same issue as Rory regarding *multi-cell execution* in MS365 preventing a correct result in the WeekdayName function; edit works perfectly now with single cell loop.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in a module. This is a UDF which you can use as a worksheet function.

```
Function WeekdayNamer(cell As Range) As String
WeekdayNamer = WeekdayName(Weekday(cell, vbMonday))
End Function
```

and in a cell type this

```
=WeekdayNamer(cell)
```

where cell is the address you want to get the name of the day.

Example:

```
=WeekdayNamer(A61)
```